# Sending data before winsock closes in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to send data to my server when my client closes the form or when the stop button is hit and for some reason it's not working.

```
Winsock.SendData "USERLEAVES" & txtUser.Text
Winsock.Close
```

It's like the winsock is closing before the data can be sent. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the _SendComplete() event

for example, using a form level boolean :

```
Option Explicit

Private mblnClosing As Boolean

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Winsock1.SendData "USERLEAVES" & txtUser.Text
  mblnClosing = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  mblnClosing = False
End Sub

Private Sub Winsock1_SendComplete()
  If mblnClosing Then
    Winsock1.Close
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: After asking the same question on some forums I found out the best way is to handle it on the client side in the winsock close event instead of sending a packet. It's much better. Your answer definitely works but its not the best way but thank you for the answer I'll mark it as an answer for you.